# PROCCESING-Pixel operations are not supported on this device

Tags: save, processing, pixel

Any code I write that requires save(), saveFrame() or functions like loadpixels() I can't use, what's stopping me from saving edited pitcures.
Error it says its: Pixel operations are not supported on this device.

About my computer:
Windows7 ultimate Service pack 1, 64-bit
AMD A10-5800K APU with Radeon(tm) HD Graphics 3.80 GHZ

UPDATE

It works on any other computer just not mine, even some basic codes like this one for example

```
size(640,480);
background(255);
fill(44);
beginShape();
vertex(50,20);
vertex(600,160);
vertex(190,400);
endShape(CLOSE);
saveFrame("izlaz1.jpg");
```

Comment: How your `size()` function looks like?

Comment: I added some simple code..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose that your Windows' **color depth setting** is set too low.

Processing assumes that system exposes color depth as **32-bit** (RGB + alpha = 4*8bit).
This is fragment from `PGraphicsJava2D` class:

```
protected WritableRaster getRaster() {
   ...
   if (raster.getTransferType() != DataBuffer.TYPE_INT) {
     System.err.println("See https://github.com/processing/processing/issues/2010");
     throw new RuntimeException("Pixel operations are not supported on this device.");
   }
   return raster;
}
```

So *"Pixel operations are not supported"* exception is raised when your system exposes to low color depth.

Try to change your Windows' setting.

Some helper links below:

https://github.com/processing/processing/issues/2010

http://helpx.adobe.com/x-productkb/global/change-color-depth-resolution-windows.html

Comment: Thank you very much! It was excatly what you said, color depth was the problem.